# How to objectively measure RAM latency impact on performance

Tags: memory, performance, latency, benchmarking

I'm already aware of these questions:

- [how to know if RAM is my bottleneck](https://superuser.com/questions/1565848/how-to-know-if-ram-is-my-bottleneck)
- [How to determine if CPU or RAM or DISK is the bottleneck on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/239136/how-to-determine-if-cpu-or-ram-or-disk-is-the-bottleneck-on-windows-7)
- [How can I know if the speed of RAM is the bottleneck rather than CPU speed?](https://superuser.com/questions/1742604/how-can-i-know-if-the-speed-of-ram-is-the-bottleneck-rather-than-cpu-speed)

To summarize the answers: They focus on total RAM usage (amount of bytes) and paging, but not on the actual CAS latency and/or speed of the RAM.

I'm not asking about paging, nor about speed, nor about if 99% RAM usage is a bottleneck.

My question is specifically targeted at the latency of the RAM. Most RAM sold today is between 8 to 20ns true/total latency. [Performance kits](https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/1895994/origin-storage-8gb-ddr4-2666mhz-udimm-1rx8-non-ecc-12v/specificaties/) can go as low as 6ns. [Worse kits](https://tweakers.net/pricewatch/1846798/coreparts-mmkn079-4gb/specificaties/) go up to 55ns.

So my question:
*In either Windows or Linux based systems, how would I, objectively, measure how much the performance of an application is impacted by the RAM latency*?

- Which (and how?) measurements should I perform?
- How would it show up in measurements? i.e. how do I interpret the results?

Comment: The problem is that latency is highly dependent on the task being done. DDR4 can do a burst of 8 64-bit "words" so while the latency for the first word might be 20ns the total time could be 25ns for all 8 words and would hide a lot of that initial latency for bulk transfers. Single byte requests would see a penalty, but large transfers can be arranged to hide the latency in the high data rate of the memory. It makes it difficult to give an objective measure against performance.

Comment: The bottom line for RAM is MB/s or GB/s per second depending on which you prefer.  Software to benchmark memory exists.  So I would suggest running the same test on the RAM with different latency settings in the BIOS.

Comment: @cybernard I don't have objective evidence for this, or 100% proof but I hear people saying that low latency results in better 1% lows / more consistent framerates for games. If that's true then there must be a way to quantize this behavior and relate it to true latency? I'm sure other software areas could be affected by latency, where GB/s doesn't matter. Maybe to support my point of GB/s not mattering - if someone plays a First Person Shooter on the moon on a 1Gbit/s connection, then the experience will still be awful with ping times over 60s. 1Gbit/s is much better than a lot ISPs offer.

Comment: @Raf  When you say 1Gbit/sec your referring to the internet connection.  You can probably play most online games with a 100mbit connection unless your downloading large patches.  When I say gb/s I am referring to how many GB/s your RAM can process.  And its more like 20,000mb/s or 20gb/s(not bits but bytes) or more.

Comment: Even if RAM can be 114 GB/s, if it takes 60s to arrive it certainly will be worse for the use case of gaming compared to RAM which can do it in 6ns and at 20GB/s.